# How to search for a word in a file using java

Tags: java, java-me

I am writing a java program to search for a word in a text file containing a list of words in the dictionary. As you may now, this file contains about 300,000 words. I was able to come up with a program that can iterate through the words comparing each word with the input word (the word I am searching for). The problem is that this process takes a lot of time to find a word especially if the word starts with the last alphabets like x, y, or z. I want something more efficient that can find a word almost instantly.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadFile
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ReadFile rf = new ReadFile();
    rf.searchWord(args[0]);
}

private void searchWord(String token) throws IOException
{
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
            getClass().getResourceAsStream("sowpods.txt"));
    String line = null;
    // Read a single line from the file. null represents the EOF.
    while((line = readLine(reader)) != null && !line.equals(token))
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    if(line != null && line.equals(token))
    {
        System.out.println(token + " WAS FOUND.");
    }
    else if(line != null && !line.equals(token))
    {
        System.out.println(token + " WAS NOT FOUND.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(token + " WAS NOT FOUND.");
    }
    reader.close();
}

private String readLine(InputStreamReader reader) throws IOException
{
    // Test whether the end of file has been reached. If so, return null.
    int readChar = reader.read();
    if(readChar == -1)
    {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuffer string = new StringBuffer("");
    // Read until end of file or new line
    while(readChar != -1 && readChar != '\n')
    {
        // Append the read character to the string. Some operating systems
        // such as Microsoft Windows prepend newline character ('\n') with
        // carriage return ('\r'). This is part of the newline character
        // and therefore an exception that should not be appended to the
        // string.
        if(readChar != '\r')
        {
            string.append((char) readChar);
        }
        // Read the next character
        readChar = reader.read();
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

}

Please also note that I would like to use this program in a Java ME environment. Any help would be highly appreciated thanks - Jevison7x.

Comment: Implement Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Please what is Aho-Corasick algorithm.

Comment: @Jack Maney: I dont know how to use grep can you help me out?

Comment: @Jevison7x - Look at `man grep`. The documentation for `grep` is just as easily reached as that for any other built-in command line tool.

Comment: Probably that you should start looking into using a database such as SQLite for storing your list of words.

Comment: SQLite is not going to search the word faster than dedicated string matching algorithms.

Comment: That point is open to discussion in this particular case because we must read a file where the length of each line/record is variable.  However, my point is that with a dictionary of 300000 words, chances are high that in the future, he will need something more sophisticated than simply storing them in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fgrep` (`fgrep` is activated by `-F` to `grep`) ([Linux man page of fgrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fgrep)):

```
grep -F -f dictionary.txt inputfile.txt
```

The dictionary file should contain the words one on each line.

Not sure if it is still accurate, but [Wikipedia article on grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep#Variations) mentions the use of [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) in `fgrep`, which is an algorithm that builds an automata based on a fixed **dictionary** for quick string matching.

Anyway, you can have a look at the [list of string searching algorithms on a finite set of patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_finite_set_of_patterns) on Wikipedia. These are the more efficient ones to work with when searching for words in dictionary.

Comment: Guys please I just want a sample program/code that could efficiently match these words. Sorry I left Computer Science four years ago.

Comment: @Jevison7x: If you want to do the job, just use grep. If you want the code, grep is open source.

Comment: @Jevison7x - Stack Overflow is not a site whose members exist purely to vomit out code snippets for you on command. You are expected to [put forth some kind of effort](http://whathaveyoutried.com).

Comment: @Jack Maney - I just read your "put forth some kind of effort" article and I want to ask, didn't I try something? What about the code I pasted? Isn't that my effort? You just make me feel people in stack overflow aren't helpful but I don't want to believe that. Your suggestion to use grep is out of scope and just proves you didn't read through my question completely. grep is a linux command, but I'm not using linux! I dont even have a linux OS! I just wanted to write a simple mobile application in Java and I needed help in searching for words in a dictionary file efficiently that's all.

Comment: @Jevison7x: You can install MinGW or Cygwin to get `grep` on Windows. You never said anything about writing a mobile application - so we assume you want to make it work on desktop. This is why putting background information into your question is important, so that you narrow down the answer to what you want. As for the implementation of the algorithm, try to search on Google for existing implementation. [A simple search](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=java+aho-corasick+algorithm) gives one implementation as the first result.

Comment: @Jevison7x: Since the algorithms I quoted are not trivial to write, I only put up the name of the algorithm as clue for you to search. I know the application of the algorithm, but I never use or implement one myself, so I cannot judge which one is good implementation to recommend.